# loading shipping methods is very slow

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, shipping-methods

My Magento website is pretty fast. Pages are loading within 2 a 3 seconds. I'm using the compiler, and APC caching.

Also my checkout is fast, except when it's loading the shipping costs. I'm disabled all shipping methods to check if it's due to a plugin. But still, when I disabled everything, loading the shipping methods is very slow.

Especially /saveBilling is slow (1.3 minute).
Strange thing is that it was fast before and I didn't did anything.

[image]

EDIT:

I think I have a good Blackfire profile now. Generating this profile took me about 1.42 minutes. The other profiles were pretty fast, so nothing was wrong with that I think.

https://blackfire.io/profiles/12909e01-127e-4298-9409-76adbb8803ad/graph

Comment: Enable magento log and check log.May be there are some issue.

Comment: This could be a number of things, a slow database, limited resources on your server, an outgoing API call with a slow response. A tool like New Relic, Blackfire or any other profiler will give you a lot more insight. Try to provide us with more debugging info

Comment: sander,i am agree with u

Comment: Ok, I installed Blackfire. I'm new to this so I have to learn how to read the outcome. In the meantime, this is the profile report when I click on next in my checkout page. https://blackfire.io/profiles/62aecccd-6199-4ced-8e28-8383252a7c48/graph.

Comment: Hm, nothing that looks out of the ordinary. From this I don't think I can determine what it could be

Comment: Have you also seen my profile report on saveBilling? I edited my question. https://blackfire.io/profiles/dd712d5c-0408-4be0-a142-20a6a8f85615/graph

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, thanks to @sander by pointing me on Blackfire. 
In my latest profile I found out that the code was executing a DHL shipping method. A method we are not using and is deprecated by Magento.

disabling the deprecated DHL function fixed the loading problem.

Comment: I am facing performance issue with FedEx shipping method with fresh magento only, I am not able to find root cause of this, Could you please help on this?